# Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database 'db'

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run the `mysql/mysql-server` docker image on a cloud container that I have, in order to connect from another container running another docker image and store data and what not in the database, as is normal.

So, reading which environment variables did what over at [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/), I set the following variables as a test.

[image]

Connecting from the other docker image, should work if I configured everything, however, the logs says otherwise.

```
Access denied for user 'rolauser'@'%' to database 'test'
```

The line of my program that attempts to connect to the database is the following.

```
conn.connect("test", "confidential.hostname.here", "rolauser", "testtesttest");
```

I'm using `libsqlpp` as I'm working in C++, but the problem is unrelated to that program.

---

So, I have an idea of what could be going wrong. After doing some research, I have discovered that SQL servers, distinguish between users logging in from different hosts.

My thinking is that by setting a user and password via environment variables, the SQL server might be assigning this information only to `rolauser @ localhost`. As I'm accessing the database from outside the container running the server, I don't have `localhost` as my hostname, thus not being able to access the database.

I don't know what else could be going wrong. I'm aware that I could try building my own image that runs a custom init file upon container startup to create the database, user and password for a wildcard hostname manually, though I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong first instead of going for a different solution.

Comment: Search that docker hub page for `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST`

Comment: @DusanBajic I'm not attempting to access the database with the root user, since I know I have to be in localhost for that.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully. Anyway, from [source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh): `... "CREATE USER '"$MYSQL_USER"'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ...` so something else is wrong

Comment: Have you confirmed that rolauser user has all the right GRANT permissions to that table?

Comment: @JayDorsey Running the container locally and logging in as the root user, I can confirm that I have the right permissions on that table, and I have logged in to rolauser succesfully.